# What is the best way to edit a dynamic html table in c#?

Tags: c#, html

From Access, I was able to post a table (access table) to html table. From the database to the dataTable, then to html table that includes dyanmic radio Button per row of the html table.

when a radio button is selected and edit button is pressed, the selected row should be edited. What is the best way to do this? should I placed the selected htmlRow to datatable, then post the datatable to a list?

below is my code

```
HtmlTableRow htmlrow=new HtmlTableRow();
htmlrow.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell() {InnerText = ""}); // creates an empty cell on row0, column0

//copy headings from datatable
foreach (DataColumn column in datatable.Columns)
{
  htmlrow.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell() {InnerText = column.ColumnName});
}
//add new row
table1.Rows.Add(htmlrow);

//place values in html table from datatable
foreach (DataRow row in datatable.Rows)
{
 htmlrow = new HtmlTableRow();
 table1.Rows.Add(htmlrow);
 RadioButton rad = new RadioButton();
 rad.GroupName = "name"
 rad.Attributes.Add("value", row[0].ToString());

//create first cell in a row with radioButton
HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell()
htmlrow.Cells.Add(cell);
cell.Controls.Add(rad)

//add cell to the current row with the values from the datatable
  for each (DataColumn column in datatable.Columns)
  {
    htmlrow.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell() {InnerText= row[column].ToString()});

  }
}
//the current output is a table, with radioButton on its first column. 
//the radioButton can only select one, which already works
//i already have an existing EditButton

//code below to be able to edit the html table named table1
```

What is the best way to edit an html table and save the edited portion back to the DB?
When the EditButton is pressed, should it copy the selected rowSelected to a list/gridview/etc so the user can edit?
After the user has editted and pressed saved, should it be wise to copy the data from list/gridview/etc to htmlTable. then from html table, i copy back to dataTable so I could save the data to the DB?

Comment: The question is not so clear... can you please explain what exactly you are doing and what outcome you need

Comment: i edited my question, i hope that explains better